# to automate Google chrome web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

Can automation be done in Google chrome that needs to perform the below function
1. Enter a job name that needs to be monitored
2. Click a refresh button in the web page (not the whole refresh button of Google chrome page that appears in left hand side corner) periodically
3. Open each sub job under the main job by clicking a folder type button and monitor whether its running or failed by differentiating the icons ( green color for running , red color for failed)
4. Alert needs to be prompted immediately if all the sub jobs are completed successfully or if any of the sub job is failed

Is it feasible without using celenium tool?
Awaiting for the reply

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) should perfectly fit for all your needs.

## What is Selenium?

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it! **What you do with that power is entirely up to you.** Primarily, it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that. Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!) also be automated as well.